# Problems bundling Tensorflow with Pyinstaller - No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer_v1'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pyinstaller

I've been having some problems with TensorFlow and Pyinstaller. My app works just fine on the terminal, but when I try to bundle it, it keeps crashing. The interface loads out, but when I try to predict some data with TensorFlow I get the error message: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer_v1'**.
Has someone had this problem before? Do you guys know how to solve it?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import keras.engine #I have tried this, but it did not work

(...)

def model_creator(loss_function, opt):
    # Define inputs with predefined shape
    inputs = Input(shape=(5,)) # <<<The error occurred at this line>>>

    # Build network
    Layer1 = Dense(units=20, activation = 'sigmoid')
    Layer2 = Dense(units=20, activation = 'sigmoid')
    
    output1 = Layer1(inputs)
    #output2 = Layer2(output1)
    last_output = Layer2(output1)

    # Predict the parameters
    outputs = Dense(2)(last_output)

    # Construct model
    model = Model(
        inputs=inputs, 
        outputs=outputs
    )

    model.compile(
        loss = loss_function, 
        optimizer = opt
    )
    return model

(...)
```

Answer (score -1):

Funny enough, for some reason, I could install every library with conda, but TensorFlow (I have used pip) 'cause some conflicts. After I have created a new env using just pip, the problem solved itself.